# Applying custom style to bootstrap select .dropdown-menu.open

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to apply custom styles to a particular bootstrap select control's dropdown menu based on its id? I have a bootstrap select control called myControl:

```
<select name="named[]" class="selectpicker show-tick dropup"
                        data-dropupAuto="true"
                        data-container="#mainContainer"
                        id="myControl" data-width="90%" title="Select your data"></select>
```

when I click on it and the dropdown opens, I want to apply some custom styles using css. I can do it generically by using:

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu.open {
width: 250px !important;
overflow: auto !important;
background-color: red !important;
}
```

But this applies the style to all the bootstrap select controls in my application. I want to be able to do it for one particular control. I tried giving the id:

```
#myControl .dropdown-menu.open {
width: 250px !important;
overflow: auto !important;
background-color: red !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Sorry if it is a stupid question, I am not very good with javascript and css and this is driving me a bit crazy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your html too!

Comment: I did, I hope that's what you meant..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it snippet helps and i have add same css

```css
.myClass {
  color: red; width:200px;
}

.myClass option { background:#000; color:#fff}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="named[]" class="selectpicker myClass show-tick dropup" data-dropupAuto="true" data-container="#mainContainer" id="myControl"  data-width="90%" title="Select your data">
  <option>Hi</option>
  <option>Hello</option>
</select>
```

```
.myClass {
  color: red; width:200px;
}

.myClass option { background:#000; color:#fff}
```

Comment: Thank you. Finally managed to get it to work by adding .myClass .dropdown-menu.open {
    width: 250px !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
} Choosing this as accepted answer as it was closest to what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a class to it using jquery. Check below snippet for reference. Hope it helps.

```js
$('#myControl').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('myClass');
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="named[]" class="selectpicker show-tick dropup" data-dropupAuto="true" data-container="#mainContainer" id="myControl" data-width="90%" title="Select your data">
      <option>Hi</option>
      <option>Hello</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this applies the style to the button also. I want to be able to apply it only to the open dropdown contents, is there any way to do that?

Comment: If you want to add only when dropdown opened. you can check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked but again it was applying the changes to button too onclick. Finally managed to do it by modifying it a bit and giving style as .myClass .dropdown-menu.open in css.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group [data-id="myControl"] + .dropdown-menu.open {
 width: 250px !important;
 overflow: auto !important;
 background-color: red !important;
}
```

try this.

Comment: Not working, sorry :( Tried with and without spaces but the styles are not applying. If I remove the data-id it works..arghh

Answer (score 0):

Hi try mine and see if it helps you with your requirement.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
<option class="mystyle">1</option>
<option class="mystyle">2</option>
<option class="mystyle">3</option>
<option class="mystyle">4</option>
```

CSS:

```
.mystyle{
 color: red;
 }
```

Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w78y1o3k/3/).

Comment: Thank you, this worked too but I did not want to apply styles for options individually. I wanted to do it for the dropdown thing as a whole. But it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes to an specific selectpicker using its `setStyle` method, for example:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('setStyle', 'btn btn-primary');
```

you can also add or remove classes, as pointed out here:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/